# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList/forEach' of undefined solution?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to coding and am trying to create a Tetris game. However, I've run into a few errors where I don't know the solution. Within the javascript I'm getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList/forEach' of undefined in two separate sections.

The error for "forEach" appears at "//draw/undraw tetros" and the error for classList appears at the bottom of the code at classList.add('tetromino').

If anyone knows how I can fix this, it would be much appreciated. :)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
document.querySelector('.grid');
let squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.grid div'));
const ScoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const StartBtn = document.querySelector('#start-button');
const width = 10;
let nextRandom = 0;

// The Tetrominoes//
const lTetromino = [
  [1, width+1, width*2+1, 2],
  [width, width+1, width+2, width*2+2],
  [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*2],
  [width, width*2, width*2+1, width*2+2]
  ]

const zTetromino = [
  [0, width, width+1, width*2+1],
  [width+1, width+2, width*2, width*2+1],
  [0, width, width+1, width*2+1],
  [width+1, width+2, width*2, width*2+1]
  ]

const tTetromino = [
 [1, width, width+1, width+2],
 [1, width+1, width+2, width*2+1],
 [width, width+1, width+2, width*2+1],
 [1, width+1, width*2+1]
 ]

const oTetromino = [
 [0, 1, width, width+1],
 [0, 1, width, width+1],
 [0, 1, width, width+1],
 [0, 1, width, width+1]
 ]

const iTetromino = [
 [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*3+1],
 [width, width+1, width+2, width+3],
 [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*3+1],
 [width, width+1, width+2, width+3]
]

const theTetrominoes = [lTetromino, zTetromino, tTetromino, oTetromino, iTetromino]

let currentPosition = 4
let currentRotation = 0

//randomly select a tetromino and its first rotation
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*theTetrominoes.length)
let current = theTetrominoes[random][0]

// draw tetromino
function draw() {
  current.forEach(index => {
    squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('tetromino')

})
}

//undraw the Tetrominoe
function undraw() {
  current.forEach(index => {
   squares[currentPosition + index].classList.remove('tetromino')

})
}

//make the tetromino move down every second
timerId = setInterval(moveDown, 1000)

//assign funtion to keycodes
function control(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 37) {
    moveLeft()
  } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    rotate()
  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    moveRight()
  } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    moveDown()
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', control)

//move down function
function moveDown() {
  undraw()
  currentPosition += width
  draw()
  freeze()
}

//freeze
function freeze() {
  if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index + width].classList
  .contains('taken'))) {
    current.forEach(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('taken'))
    //start a new tetro falling
    random = nextRandom
    nextRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * theTetrominoes.length)
    current = theTetrominoes[random][currentRotation]
    currentPosition = 4
    draw()
    displayShape()
  }
}

//move the tetro left, unless is at the edge or there is a blockage
  function moveLeft() {
  undraw()
  const isAtLeftEdge = current.some(index => (currentPosition + index) % width === 0)

  if(!isAtLeftEdge) currentPosition -=1

  if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.contains('taken'))) {
    currentPosition +=1
}

draw()
}

//move the tetro right, unless is at the edge or there is a blockage
  function moveRight() {
  undraw()
  const isAtRightEdge = current.some(index => (currentPosition + index) % width
  === width -1)

  if(!isAtRightEdge) currentPosition +=1

  if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.contains('taken'))) {
    currentPosition -=1
  }
  draw()
}

//rotate retro
function rotate() {
  undraw()
  currentRotation ++
  if(currentRotation === current.length) { //if the current rotation gets to 4, make it go back to 0
    currentRotation = 0
  }
  current = theTetrominoes[random][currentRotation]
  draw()
}

//show up-next tetro in mini-grid
const displaySquares = document.querySelectorAll('mini-grid div')
const displayWidth = 4
let displayIndex = 0

// the tetro without currentRotation
const upNextTetrominoes = [
  [1, displayWidth+1, displayWidth*2+1, 2], //lTetromino
  [0, displayWidth, displayWidth+1, displayWidth*2+1], //zTetromino
  [1, displayWidth, displayWidth+1, displayWidth+2], //tTetromino
  [0, 1, displayWidth, displayWidth+1], //oTetromino
  [1, displayWidth+1, displayWidth*2+1, displayWidth*3+1] //iTetromino
]

//display the shape in the mini-grid display
function displayShape() {
  //remove any trace of a tetromino form the entire grid
  displaySquares.forEach(square => {
    square.classList.remove('tetromino')
  })
  upNextTetrominoes[nextRandom].forEach( index => {
    displaySquares[displayIndex + index].classList.add('tetromino')
  })
}


})
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve], [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0):

[Please provide minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However with the code provided following seem the problems

**Problem 1**

> The error for "forEach" appears at "//draw/undraw tetros"

This is because you are nesting arrays at 3 level but trying to get like this  `let current = theTetrominoes[random][0]` which means you are trying to access 2d array which it's not.

**Solution**

Try to make it 2d array or access it like 3d array:

`theTetrominoes[random][0][desired_index]`

**Problem 2**

> error for classList appears at the bottom of the code at classList.add('tetromino')

You are passing `index` as the first parameter to `forEach()` which in fact is an actual item stored.

**Solution**

You should do something like this:

```
current.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log(index)
    });
```